# How to select fields using doctrine 2 query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following query I'm executing in Symfony2 Repository. The query looks like

```
                 $q = $this
                    ->createQueryBuilder('m')
                    ->select(array('m.reciever','m.created','m.id','m.subject'))
                    ->where('m.reciever = ?1')
                    ->orderBy('m.id','DESC')
                    ->setMaxResults( '?2' )
                    ->setFirstResult( '?3' )
                    ->setParameter(1,$id)
                    ->setParameter(2,$itemsPerPage)
                    ->setParameter(3,$offset)
                    ->getQuery();
```

Where reciever, created, id, and subject are fields part of my message entity. I do not need to specify which entity I am selecting from. The error I keep getting is such...

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'reciever, m.created,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

I'm not sure what a state field path expression is or what the syntax might be. It seems like everything should be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have something like this:=?

```
 $q = $this
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('m.reciever, m.created ,m.id , m.subject')
                ->from('/Acme/Entity/DemoEntity', 'm')
                ->where('m.reciever = ?1')
                ->orderBy('m.id','DESC')
                ->setMaxResults( '?2' )
                ->setFirstResult( '?3' )
                ->setParameter(1,$id)
                ->setParameter(2,$itemsPerPage)
                ->setParameter(3,$offset)
                ->getQuery();
```

Im not sure but I think you use the array syntax only if you have multiple tables to join together: *array('m.reciever, m.created', 'p.user, p.id')*.

Answer (score 8):

When you use the `select()` method, you override the default one which is in `$this->createQueryBuilder('m')` . That's why you lost the `m` alias. To avoide this, use an `addSelect()` or specify the `alias` in the `from()` method:

```
->from('Bundle:Entity', 'ALIAS')
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help u..

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $q = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('m.reciever,m.created,m.id,m.subject')
            ->from('bundle:entity','m')
            ->where('m.reciever = ?1')
            ->orderBy('m.id','DESC')
            ->setMaxResults( '?2' )
            ->setFirstResult( '?3' )
            ->setParameter(1,$id)
            ->setParameter(2,$itemsPerPage)
            ->setParameter(3,$offset)
            ->getQuery();
```